# Setting border property on clicked element and not the parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to enable clicking on specific element on the page, and after click to set border on that element. You can find working example here [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/GO9xQRJzMvUy5dDSamFC?p=preview)
And some code:

```
   <div>
      <a href="#">Test</a>
    </div>

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a, div').on('click', function() {
    $(this).css({'border-color': 'red'});
  })
});
```

The problem is, if anchor element is clicked, div as a parent element also gets click event, and the border is set there. Is there a way to restrict click event only to most specific element(in this case anchor) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could stop the event propagation, but it's discouraged as there could be some library which does something if the user clicks away/anywhere. A better solution is this one:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a, div').on('click', function(e) {
    if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) { //Don't do anything if we already processed that event.
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).css({'border-color': 'red'});
    }
  })
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your current selector targets all `a` and `div` elements. The selector below target all `a` elements in a `div` element. More accurately, you can use `div > a`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div > a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).css({'border-color': 'red'});
  })
});
```

The construct you're trying to use is: `jQuery( selector [, context] )` .. see `http://api.jquery.com/jquery/`:

jQuery( selector [, context ] )Returns: jQuery
Description: Accepts a string containing a CSS selector which is then used to match a set of elements.

```
jQuery( selector [, context ] )

selector
Type: Selector
A string containing a selector expression

context
Type: Element or jQuery
A DOM Element, Document, or jQuery to use as context
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply focus on the element that was clicked, using `event.target`:

```
$('a, div').on('click', function (e) {
    e.target.style.borderColor = 'red';
});
```

```js
$('a, div').on('click', function (e) {
    e.target.style.borderColor = 'red';
});
```

```css
div, a {
    border: 2px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><a href="#">link text</a></div>
<div><a href="#">link text</a></div>
<div><a href="#">link text</a></div>
```

Or, to use a slightly more-jQuery approach:

```
$('a, div').on('click', function (e) {
    $(e.target).css({'border-color' : 'red'});
});
```

```js
$('a, div').on('click', function (e) {
    $(e.target).css({'border-color' : 'red'});
});
```

```css
div, a {
    border: 2px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><a href="#">link text</a></div>
<div><a href="#">link text</a></div>
<div><a href="#">link text</a></div>
```

References:

- [`Event.target`](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a, div').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).prop('tagName').toLowerCase() == 'a') {
      $(this).css({'border-color': 'red'});
    }
  })
});
```

This will check if the anchor element is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div a').on('click', function() {
    $(this).css({'border-color': 'red'});
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use event.stopPropagation() to prevent the event from bubbling up the DOM tree.

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Answer (score 0):

the issue was click event was being propagated to div from anchor tag , anchor being the child element of div, so just we need to stop the propagation.

Check below code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a, div').on('click', function(event) {
    $(event.currentTarget).css({'border-color': 'red'});
 event.stopPropagation();
  })
});
```

```css
div {
  padding: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
}

a {
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
      <a href="#">Test</a>
    </div>
```